# Create Github Actions choice input options from a file

Tags: github, deployment, workflow, github-actions

Right now, we're running a **manual workflow** in order to deploy our product to production. We have one input and we can choose our brand which needs to be deployed.

It's including **options** like

```
on:
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      dst:
        type: choice
        description: Select destination brand
        required: true
        options:
          - A
          - B
          - C
```

and so on

My question is, is it possible to read this options from a file (like a text file which is in our project)? I looked at it but I couldn't see a solution from others.

Thank you so much!

Comment: I was looking for something similar, trying to populate input options using tags from the repo to trigger action using that tag. It would be nice to have.

Answer (score 2):

No - it's not possible to have dynamic workflow configurations at the moment, I'm afraid.

The solution I personally use is to trigger this type of workflow using [workflow_dispatch](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#workflow_dispatch) event with proper `input` options.

Instead of triggering it manually on web, you can have a script that locally reads the file with all options and let you pick desired option locally, then it will trigger `workflow_dispatch` event with the selected input.

Another alternative if you don't want local parsing will be to make input as regular `string` and then add a step in your workflow that will read a file after `actions/checkout` and check if it's a valid option.

Comment: Can you elaborate please?